# Read txt file and return an array of objects that has multiple fields

Tags: java, arrays, object, bufferedreader

I have a text file, in which each line is an `Movie` instance, and `Movie` object's fields are separated by a tab.
I need to read it and return an `array` of object (each line), that has multiple fields. I don't know how to make the array of `Movie` object ( i.e. `Movie[]`) and `return` it.

**Sample text file I'm reading:**

```
id  title      price  

001 titanic    2

002 lady bird  3
```

**The following is what I've got so far.**

```
public class Loader {
    //private String csvFile;
    private static final Resource tsvResource = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext().getResource("classpath:movies.txt");
    private static InputStream movieIS = null;

    public Loader() {
        try {
            movieIS = tsvResource.getInputStream();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Movie[] loadMovies() {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String[] tempArray = new String[100];
        int id;
        String title;
        String rating;
        String synopsis;
        String genre;
        String director;
        String[] actors;
        int price;
        int runtime;

        int index = 0;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(movieIS));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                index++;
                String[] data = line.split("\\t");
                id = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                title = data[1];
                rating = data[2];
                synopsis = data[3];
                genre = data[4];
                director = data[5];
                actors = data[6].split(";");
                price = Integer.parseInt(data[7]);
                runtime = Integer.parseInt(data[8]);
            }
            String[] lines = new String[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                lines[i] = br.readLine();

            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show Movie class?

Comment: since your Movies are loaded from file dynamically, it's better to use an ArrayList<Movie> instead of array. put this line before while: List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>(); and inside while add a new Movie to that list like this: movies.add(new Movie(...));

Comment: You can use ArrayList instead of an array. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've **almost** got this. You can create the `Movie` object from the fields you've extracted (like `title`, `rating` , `synopsis`, `actors` etc.) and add them to your `array`.

Also I'd suggest you to use `ArrayList` instead of `array` for your movies (unless you're absolute sure of the number of movies you'd have)

**Your `loadMovies` method would look like this:**

```
public static List<Movie> loadMovies() {

        // Initialize your movie list
        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();

        String line = "", title, rating, synopsis, genre, director;
        int id, price, runtime, index = 0;
        String[] actors;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(movieIS))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                index++;
                String[] data = line.split("\\t");
                id = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                title = data[1];
                rating = data[2];
                synopsis = data[3];
                genre = data[4];
                director = data[5];
                actors = data[6].split(";");
                price = Integer.parseInt(data[7]);
                runtime = Integer.parseInt(data[8]);

                // Create your Movie object here,
                // note that I'm using constructor here,
                // You can also use setters for optional fields as well
                Movie movie = new Movie(id, title, rating, synopsis, genre, director, actors, price, runtime);

                movieList.add(movie);
            }
            String[] lines = new String[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                lines[i] = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //return movieList
        return movieList;
    }
```

Note that I've combined the `variable` declarations and `try-catch` blocks as well in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
 ArrayList <> al = new ArrayList<Movie>();

int index = 0;
try{
    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(movieIS));


    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        index++;
        String[] data=line.split("\\t");
        id =Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        title=data[1];
        rating=data[2];
        synopsis=data[3];
        genre=data[4];
        director=data[5];
        actors=data[6].split(";");
        price= Integer.parseInt(data[7]);
        runtime=Integer.parseInt(data[8]);
        Movie mv = new Movie();
        // load into mv
        al.add(mv);
       }
}
```

and return at the end like this:

```
return al.toArray();
```